# Trying to call the rest api using get in Angular 5

Tags: html, angular, rest, api

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
configUrl = '/config.json';

getConfig() {
  return this.http.get(this.configUrl);
}
@Component({
  selector: 'app-rest',
  templateUrl: './rest.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./rest.component.css']
})

@Injectable()
export class RestComponent  {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
}
```

i have configured the url in the `config.json`

```
{
  "heroesUrl": "http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx:3001/getAllData"  
}
```

i am  calling the rest api with using the heroesUrl in another file and i have linked the file in my main folder  but i am getting errors plese help me out for calling the rest api in angular

2) In congig url i am passing the url with the extension of config.json

Comment: If you're calling it in another file, it would be helpful to see the other file. It would also be helpful to see the errors you're getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the http.get inside your component code,

```
export class RestComponent  {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  getConfig() {
   return this.http.get(this.configUrl);
  }
}
```